# EXTJS 4.0.7 css file shows different results then from the web link

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I am using extjs 4.0.7 library in my project. I noticed that if i use web link reference to css file like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      href="http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.7-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css">
```

The screen displays fine, but if I just include same ext-all.css file in my project

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ext-all.css"/>
```

The screen comes out distorted. This happens in IE browser only and works fine in FF and Chrome. Did anyone have this problem before? Any solution?

Comment: Do you have html4 oder html5 index? Sometimes the self closing tag makes problems.

Comment: html4, i've tried with and without closing tag made no difference.

Comment: I am still having this problem, so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Is the file content exact the same in both files?